# comparing variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am in a predicament. I have been trying to compare two variables in javascript and then assign a class to parent element if matched. But i am having no success in this. I have searched through all possible codes and tried them but not able to get it working. The code i have written so far is as below:

```
$('div#encased a').click(function(){
        $('ul#filter .current').removeClass('current');
        var class_name = ($(this).parent().attr('class').replace('-',' '));
        var className = class_name.toString();
        alert(className);
        $('ul#filter li').each(function(){
            /*1st version
            var filterValue = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            var filterValstr = filterValue.toString();
            alert(filterValstr);
            if(filterValstr==className)
            {
                alert("match!")
                $(this).parent().addClass('current');   
            }*/

            /*2nd version*/
            if($(this).text().toLowerCase() == class_name)
            {
                $(this).parent().addClass('current');   
            }
            /*this works which according to me means it is not entering the if clause
            else{
                $(this).parent().fadeOut('slow').addClass('hidden');    
            }*/
        });
    });
```

As per my knowledge the value is not going inside the if command at all as i tried using else function and that works. I am sure theres some silly error i am doing. I have tried 2 methods here and i have commented one but presented both of them here to know if any of them should be correct.

Basically on click of an image in my div#encased element the class name of the image is taken and then compared with the text in the filter menu above. If it matches the matched filter text should be assigned the class of current. Hope you are getting what i am trying to explain. Please help. thanks

Comment: `alert(className);` and `alert(filterValstr);` output?

Comment: Shouldn't you be comparing it with className  instead of class_name ?

Comment: @UmairP. `str.toString() == str` ?!

Comment: if($(this).text().toLowerCase() == className ) instead of if($(this).text().toLowerCase() == class_name)

Comment: @UmairP As I already told you, it doesn't matter, `str.toString() === str`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't clear, and kind of a spaghetti one, but maybe your problem is with white spaces, try trim them

```
var filterValue = $.trim($(this).text().toLowerCase());
```

And you should know that `string.toString()` return the string...
Example:

```
var str = "bla bla bla";
alert(str.toString === str); // true!
```

Comment: that's how I do it too: trim + lowerCase

Comment: @gion_13. I hope without the brilliant `.toString()`... :)

Comment: Awesome guys.. trim worked... Thanks @gdoron and everyone who pitched in.

Comment: Hey btw @gdoron... what did u mean by my code was unclear.. i mean i thought aligning is to be done, right? Could you let me know what would be a clear code for mine. It would be of a great help.. thanks

Comment: @user1447068. It isn't not clear because, you use `.toString()` when you don't have to. You didn't show what the output of the alert, and didn't show us how the HTML looks like.

Comment: Oh ok @gdoron. Sorry my 1st post, so a lil unclear i guess. The .toString() was just a desperate attempt to get it working. I have now removed that and it worked using trim method. Thanks.